# Mysql crashes multiple times randomly when an update or a delete query is executed

Tags: mysql, crash, centos7, mysql-8.0, percona

We are trying to execute consecutive update queries. The same query is working most of the time. But randomly one of the query causes the issue.

Once we faced this issue with delete query.

I think its corrupting data directory.

Mysql installed: mysql  Ver 8.0.19-10 for Linux on x86_64 (Percona Server (GPL), Release 10, Revision f446c04)

Please refer mysql configuration below.

```
    datadir=xxxxx
    socket=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
    sql_mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION
    log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
    pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
    mysqlx_max_connections = 1001
    max_connections = 1001
    innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 400
    gtid_mode = ON
    enforce_gtid_consistency = ON
    master_info_repository = TABLE
    relay_log_info_repository = TABLE
    binlog_checksum = NONE
    log_slave_updates = ON
    log_bin = binlog
    binlog_format = ROW
    transaction_write_set_extraction = XXHASH64
    loose-group_replication_bootstrap_group = OFF
    loose-group_replication_start_on_boot = ON
    loose-group_replication_ssl_mode = DISABLED
    loose-group_replication_recovery_use_ssl = 0

    loose-group_replication_group_name = xxxxx
    loose-group_replication_ip_whitelist = xxxxx
    loose-group_replication_group_seeds = xxxxx
    loose-group_replication_single_primary_mode = OFF
    loose-group_replication_enforce_update_everywhere_checks = ON
    require_secure_transport=OFF
    server_id = 3
    bind-address = "0.0.0.0"
    report-host = xxxxxx
    loose-group_replication_local_address = "xxxxxx"
    relay-log=localhost-relay-bin
    max_allowed_packet=750M
    loose-group_replication_transaction_size_limit= 750M
    loose-group_replication_member_expel_timeout = 60
    loose-group_replication_poll_spin_loops=100
    binlog_row_image=MINIMAL
    loose-group_replication_compression_threshold=100
    loose-group_replication_autorejoin_tries=100
    innodb_read_io_threads=64
    innodb_write_io_threads=64
    binlog_expire_logs_seconds = 604800
    mysqlx_max_allowed_packet= 750M
    log_output = 'TABLE'
    general_log = 'ON'
```

Here is the error log when certain update and delete queries are executed.

```
    13:07:29 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
    Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
    Thread pointer: 0x7f0351283880
    Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
    where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
    terribly wrong...
    stack_bottom = 7f02d3454a9f thread_stack 0x46000
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x200b90d]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x333) [0x11cf0f3]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf630) [0x7f04d943d630]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_charpos_mb4+0x43) [0x272b1d3]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Field_blob::key_cmp(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) const+0x64) [0x12c3f74]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(key_cmp(KEY_PART_INFO*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)+0xac) [0xf1a0cc]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::compare_key_in_buffer(unsigned char const*) const+0x94) [0xdce924]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x224a8e0]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(row_search_mvcc(unsigned char*, page_cur_mode_t, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x136d) [0x2252cdd]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::general_fetch(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x1ec) [0x20d63ec]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_index_next_same(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)+0x18e) [0xdc9d6e]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::read_range_next()+0x21) [0x20b29b1]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::multi_range_read_next(char**)+0x45) [0xdd1a95]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_multi_range_read_next(char**)+0x28) [0xdcd978]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(QUICK_RANGE_SELECT::get_next()+0x56) [0xf51646]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(IndexRangeScanIterator::Read()+0x37) [0xfa62c7]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_update::update_single_table(THD*)+0x17d4) [0x11565b4]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x418) [0x10dfc58]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x3cdb) [0x108da4b]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*, bool)+0x408) [0x108fa48]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x2015) [0x1091ff5]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Srv_session::execute_command(enum_server_command, COM_DATA const*, CHARSET_INFO const*, st_command_service_cbs const*, cs_text_or_binary, void*)+0x24e) [0x11d2dde]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Sql_data_context::execute_server_command(enum_server_command, COM_DATA const&, xpl::iface::Resultset*)+0x78) [0x26401a8]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Sql_data_context::execute_sql(char const*, unsigned long, xpl::iface::Resultset*)+0x30) [0x2640490]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Crud_command_handler::execute_crud_update(Mysqlx::Crud::Update const&)+0x153) [0x2636f73]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Dispatcher::dispatch(ngs::Message_request const&)+0xac) [0x260c4bc]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Dispatcher::execute(ngs::Message_request const&)+0xda) [0x260c6fa]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Session::handle_ready_message(ngs::Message_request const&)+0x80) [0x2606a30]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Client::handle_message(ngs::Message_request*)+0x93) [0x26612f3]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Message_decoder::parse_protobuf_frame(unsigned char, unsigned int, xpl::Vio_input_stream*)+0x2cc) [0x266508c]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Message_decoder::parse_and_dispatch(unsigned char, unsigned int, xpl::Vio_input_stream*)+0x2c) [0x266675c]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Protocol_decoder::read_and_decode_impl(xpl::iface::Waiting_for_io*)+0x9b) [0x2666d1b]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Protocol_decoder::read_and_decode(xpl::iface::Waiting_for_io*)+0x25) [0x2666fb5]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Client::read_one_message_and_dispatch()+0x43) [0x26617a3]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Client::run(bool)+0x8b) [0x26619bb]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Scheduler_dynamic::worker()+0x518) [0x2672178]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x24e57dc]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ea5) [0x7f04d9435ea5]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f04d75ba8dd]

    Trying to get some variables.
    Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
    Query (7f033a7054a8): UPDATE `ERCA_KB`.`Rules` SET doc=JSON_SET(JSON_SET(doc,'$.type','Inactive'),'$._id',JSON_EXTRACT(`doc`,'$._id')) WHERE (((((((JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.Data_Level') = 'Daily') AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.RuleId') = 'crnsanrulFcovSinrPucch_nrnbr')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.SourceTechnology') = '4g')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.SourceVendor') = 'Ericsson')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.service') = 'MBB')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.type') = 'Aug')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.latest') = 'True'))
    Connection ID (thread ID): 2741796
    Status: NOT_KILLED

    Please help us make Percona Server better by reporting any
    bugs at https://bugs.percona.com/

    You may download the Percona Server operations manual by visiting
    http://www.percona.com/software/percona-server/. You may find information
    in the manual which will help you identify the cause of the crash.
    2021-11-08T13:07:32.568543Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19-10) starting as process 26889
    2021-11-08T13:07:34.615267Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
    2021-11-08T13:07:34.625742Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
    13:29:03 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
    Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
    Thread pointer: 0x7fe63c000b90
    Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
    where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
    terribly wrong...
    stack_bottom = 7fe5ae900a9f thread_stack 0x46000
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x200b90d]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x333) [0x11cf0f3]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf630) [0x7fe6cd9a2630]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_charpos_mb4+0x43) [0x272b1d3]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Field_blob::key_cmp(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) const+0x64) [0x12c3f74]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(key_cmp(KEY_PART_INFO*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)+0xac) [0xf1a0cc]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::compare_key_in_buffer(unsigned char const*) const+0x94) [0xdce924]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x224a8e0]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(row_search_mvcc(unsigned char*, page_cur_mode_t, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x136d) [0x2252cdd]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::general_fetch(unsigned char*, unsigned int, unsigned int)+0x1ec) [0x20d63ec]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_index_next_same(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)+0x18e) [0xdc9d6e]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::read_range_next()+0x21) [0x20b29b1]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::multi_range_read_next(char**)+0x45) [0xdd1a95]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_multi_range_read_next(char**)+0x28) [0xdcd978]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(QUICK_RANGE_SELECT::get_next()+0x56) [0xf51646]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(IndexRangeScanIterator::Read()+0x37) [0xfa62c7]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_update::update_single_table(THD*)+0x17d4) [0x11565b4]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x418) [0x10dfc58]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x3cdb) [0x108da4b]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*, bool)+0x408) [0x108fa48]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x2015) [0x1091ff5]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Srv_session::execute_command(enum_server_command, COM_DATA const*, CHARSET_INFO const*, st_command_service_cbs const*, cs_text_or_binary, void*)+0x24e) [0x11d2dde]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Sql_data_context::execute_server_command(enum_server_command, COM_DATA const&, xpl::iface::Resultset*)+0x78) [0x26401a8]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Sql_data_context::execute_sql(char const*, unsigned long, xpl::iface::Resultset*)+0x30) [0x2640490]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Crud_command_handler::execute_crud_update(Mysqlx::Crud::Update const&)+0x153) [0x2636f73]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Dispatcher::dispatch(ngs::Message_request const&)+0xac) [0x260c4bc]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Dispatcher::execute(ngs::Message_request const&)+0xda) [0x260c6fa]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(xpl::Session::handle_ready_message(ngs::Message_request const&)+0x80) [0x2606a30]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Client::handle_message(ngs::Message_request*)+0x93) [0x26612f3]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Message_decoder::parse_protobuf_frame(unsigned char, unsigned int, xpl::Vio_input_stream*)+0x2cc) [0x266508c]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Message_decoder::parse_and_dispatch(unsigned char, unsigned int, xpl::Vio_input_stream*)+0x2c) [0x266675c]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Protocol_decoder::read_and_decode_impl(xpl::iface::Waiting_for_io*)+0x9b) [0x2666d1b]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Protocol_decoder::read_and_decode(xpl::iface::Waiting_for_io*)+0x25) [0x2666fb5]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Client::read_one_message_and_dispatch()+0x43) [0x26617a3]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Client::run(bool)+0x8b) [0x26619bb]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ngs::Scheduler_dynamic::worker()+0x518) [0x2672178]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x24e57dc]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ea5) [0x7fe6cd99aea5]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7fe6cbb1f8dd]

    Trying to get some variables.
    Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
    Query (7fe63c1f2588): UPDATE `ERCA_KB`.`Rules` SET doc=JSON_SET(JSON_SET(doc,'$.latest','False'),'$._id',JSON_EXTRACT(`doc`,'$._id')) WHERE (((((((JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.RuleId') = 'crnsaTermpointtoGnbdefinition') AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.SourceVendor') = 'Ericsson')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.service') = 'MBB')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.SourceTechnology') = '4g')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.Data_Level') = 'Daily')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.type') = 'CKB')) AND (JSON_EXTRACT(doc,'$.latest') = 'True'))
    Connection ID (thread ID): 528
    Status: NOT_KILLED

    Please help us make Percona Server better by reporting any
    bugs 

    You may download the Percona Server operations manual by visiting
    Percona. You may find information
    in the manual which will help you identify the cause of the crash.
    2021-11-08T13:29:05.738840Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19-10) starting as process 10135
    2021-11-08T13:29:07.485285Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
    2021-11-08T13:29:07.495313Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
    05:47:00 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
    Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
    Thread pointer: 0x7f6f1c5d89c0
    Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
    where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
    terribly wrong...
    stack_bottom = 7f6ff80a0c30 thread_stack 0x46000
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x200b90d]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x333) [0x11cf0f3]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf630) [0x7f70198bf630]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_charpos_mb4+0x43) [0x272b1d3]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Field_blob::key_cmp(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) const+0x64) [0x12c3f74]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(key_cmp(KEY_PART_INFO*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)+0xac) [0xf1a0cc]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::compare_key_in_buffer(unsigned char const*) const+0x94) [0xdce924]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x224a8e0]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(row_search_mvcc(unsigned char*, page_cur_mode_t, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x136d) [0x2252cdd]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::index_read(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, ha_rkey_function)+0x3ae) [0x20d601e]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_index_read_map(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, ha_rkey_function)+0x401) [0xdd08d1]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::read_range_first(key_range const*, key_range const*, bool, bool)+0x64) [0xdd1314]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::read_range_first(key_range const*, key_range const*, bool, bool)+0x28) [0x20b2968]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::multi_range_read_next(char**)+0x159) [0xdd1ba9]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_multi_range_read_next(char**)+0x28) [0xdcd978]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(QUICK_RANGE_SELECT::get_next()+0x56) [0xf51646]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(IndexRangeScanIterator::Read()+0x37) [0xfa62c7]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_update::update_single_table(THD*)+0x17d4) [0x11565b4]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x418) [0x10dfc58]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x3cdb) [0x108da4b]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*, bool)+0x408) [0x108fa48]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x2015) [0x1091ff5]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x204) [0x1092ce4]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x11c0050]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x24e57dc]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ea5) [0x7f70198b7ea5]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f7017a3c8dd]

    Trying to get some variables.
    Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
    Query (7f6f1c6266c8): update Rules set doc=json_set(doc,"$.latest","False") where doc->>"$.latest"="True" and doc->>"$.datetime" in ("14-06-2021 17:01:48","23-07-2021 11:30:19","30-06-2021 23:18:23","03-10-2020 16:38:04","03-10-2020 16:38:20","05-10-2021 20:01:40","02-06-2021 01:55:13","23-07-2021 11:29:51","22-03-2021 17:17:29","09-07-2021 16:32:00","23-07-2021 11:29:24","23-07-2021 11:28:58","23-07-2021 11:28:27","23-07-2021 10:52:32","02-10-2020 13:12:00","22-03-2021 12:49:10","10-08-2021 05:06:07","05-08-2021 12:39:10","23-07-2021 11:00:10","23-07-2021 11:00:59","23-07-2021 11:03:04","20-07-2021 15:12:24","23-07-2021 11:04:21","23-07-2021 11:03:48","23-07-2021 11:02:15","20-07-2021 15:20:03","06-10-2021 11:38:34","06-10-2021 11:37:18","18-06-2021 19:58:52","25-06-2021 21:57:26","20-06-2021 22:12:40","25-06-2021 21:58:10","20-06-2021 22:09:15","06-10-2021 11:40:14","06-10-2021 11:39:37","11-06-2021 00:33:33","05-10-2020 14:01:43","05-10-2020 14:00:13","05-10-2020 14:02:20","05-10-2020 13:56:13","05-10-2020 13:57:23","05-10-2020
    Connection ID (thread ID): 1247
    Status: NOT_KILLED

    Please help us make Percona Server better by reporting any
    bugs 

    You may download the Percona Server operations manual by visiting. You may find information
    in the manual which will help you identify the cause of the crash.
    2021-11-09T05:47:02.232811Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19-10) starting as process 6933
    2021-11-09T05:47:03.238504Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
    2021-11-09T05:47:03.248103Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
    2021-11-09T05:47:03.331293Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
    09:01:00 UTC - mysqld got signal 11 ;
    Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
    Thread pointer: 0x7f8c0c15f710
    Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
    where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
    terribly wrong...
    stack_bottom = 7f8b9ba03c30 thread_stack 0x46000
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x3d) [0x200b90d]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x333) [0x11cf0f3]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0xf630) [0x7f8d3fd3c630]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(my_charpos_mb4+0x43) [0x272b1d3]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Field_blob::key_cmp(unsigned char const*, unsigned int) const+0x64) [0x12c3f74]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(key_cmp(KEY_PART_INFO*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int)+0xac) [0xf1a0cc]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::compare_key_in_buffer(unsigned char const*) const+0x94) [0xdce924]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x224a8e0]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(row_search_mvcc(unsigned char*, page_cur_mode_t, row_prebuilt_t*, unsigned long, unsigned long)+0x136d) [0x2252cdd]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::index_read(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned int, ha_rkey_function)+0x3ae) [0x20d601e]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_index_read_map(unsigned char*, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, ha_rkey_function)+0x401) [0xdd08d1]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::read_range_first(key_range const*, key_range const*, bool, bool)+0x64) [0xdd1314]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(ha_innobase::read_range_first(key_range const*, key_range const*, bool, bool)+0x28) [0x20b2968]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::multi_range_read_next(char**)+0x159) [0xdd1ba9]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(handler::ha_multi_range_read_next(char**)+0x28) [0xdcd978]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(QUICK_RANGE_SELECT::get_next()+0x56) [0xf51646]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(IndexRangeScanIterator::Read()+0x37) [0xfa62c7]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_delete::delete_from_single_table(THD*)+0xd2d) [0x10242dd]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(Sql_cmd_dml::execute(THD*)+0x418) [0x10dfc58]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_execute_command(THD*, bool)+0x3cdb) [0x108da4b]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(mysql_parse(THD*, Parser_state*, bool)+0x408) [0x108fa48]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(dispatch_command(THD*, COM_DATA const*, enum_server_command)+0x2015) [0x1091ff5]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld(do_command(THD*)+0x204) [0x1092ce4]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x11c0050]
    /usr/sbin/mysqld() [0x24e57dc]
    /lib64/libpthread.so.0(+0x7ea5) [0x7f8d3fd34ea5]
    /lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d) [0x7f8d3deb98dd]

    Trying to get some variables.
    Some pointers may be invalid and cause the dump to abort.
    Query (7f8c0c671f28): delete from Rules where doc->>"$.latest"="True" and doc->>"RuleId"="crPrachconfigindex1" and doc->>"$.reponame"="Ericsson-4g" and doc->>"$.Data_Level"="Hourly" and doc->>"$.type"="CKB"
    Connection ID (thread ID): 1052
    Status: NOT_KILLED

    Please help us make Percona Server better by reporting any
    bugs 

    You may download the Percona Server operations manual by visiting
    . You may find information
    in the manual which will help you identify the cause of the crash.
    2021-11-09T09:01:02.968940Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.19-10) starting as process 708
    2021-11-09T09:01:03.748063Z 0 [System] [MY-010229] [Server] Starting XA crash recovery...
    2021-11-09T09:01:03.759115Z 0 [System] [MY-010232] [Server] XA crash recovery finished.
```

Please let me know what causes this issue. Any improvements can be done to the configuration.

Comment: Additional information request, please. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
AND very helpful information 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: max_allowed_packet=750M -- looks too high; how much RAM do you have?